# Internet connectivity

Tags: internet, browser

I want to know the different factors which will help in having faster Internet experience, i.e. faster upload and download.

Further, how do browsers like IE, Mozilla, and Opera work in enabling faster internet connections?

I am aware of the factors in network level, to have faster upload/download speeds. But just had some thoughts on whether browsers have any/some additional functionality in it's browser engine to make the connectivity faster.

Answer (score 2):

A browser won't play in 'enabling faster internet connection'. Usual methods are the own javascript engine, the own browser engine, the preferences, and how it works.
Like in Opera, it uses parallel fetching by default. You can enable that in Firefox also (the easiest method is installing the FasterFox addon). That is one part. The other parts are the engines as I said. Every browser (usually, at least the mentioned ones) comes with an own engine. Opera uses Carakan for example. They proccess the received data and the faster it is, the faster you will see the page.
Other things what can speed up your browsing are "AdBlock Plus" for Firefox, "urlfilter.ini" in Opera and using a proxy like "BFilter" for Chrome. These would block ads (and everything else you select/dont want) which saves a LOT of bandwidth and gives you much better  speed.
 Hope you meant THIS.. next time please give a better explanation about what you want..
If you want to speed up your CONNECTION (so everything), you can play with traffic shaping utilities like "CFosSpeed". It won't literally speed it up, but you will have a much better experience most likely (sometimes it works , sometimes it doesnt. Depends on your connection, router, pc, applications).

Answer (score 1):

> Basically want to know the different factors which will help in having faster Internet experience, ie. faster upload and download.

The different factors are faster upload and download.

> In this, how browsers like IE, mozilla, opera play in enabling faster internet connections ?

Internet Explorer and Mozilla detect your home router and connect to it and reconfigure it for maximum faster internet connections. Opera does not do this, it is not very good at enabling faster internet connections.

**But in all seriousness, the browser has very little to do with the performance of the internet connection. They will group HTTP requests has much as they can using HTTP Keep-Alive and maintaining a browser cache. Chrome prefetches DNS requests which is nice.
For real factors that contribute:**

1. Upload Speed
2. Download Speed
3. Latency
4. Quality of the connection (lots of packet loss makes DNS lookups unreliable and increases latency as TCP has to retransmit)
5. MTU
6. Whether you're behind a proxy and how effectively the proxy caches
7. Whether your DNS server caches DNS requests effectively
8. The connection between your PC and the router. If you have a wireless connection from 100 meters away you can expect a very slow internet connection.